# How to implement an ADT for a container with one or many values in Scala

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types, path-dependent-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

At the end of the day, here is what I want to achieve :

```
  val onePath: One = new Log(OneLocation("root"), "foo/bar").getPath()
  val manyPath: Many = new Log(ManyLocation(List("base1", "base2")), "foo/bar").getPath()
```

In order to achieve that, it seems that an ADT representing one or many value(s) is required.

Here is my implementation. Is there another/better/simpler way to implement it (I've used path dependent type and F-bounded types). is there a library that already implements it (the use case seems prety current).

```
  sealed trait OneOrMany[T <: OneOrMany[T]] {
    def map(f: String => String) : T
  }
  final case class One(a: String) extends OneOrMany[One] {
    override def map(f: String => String): One = One(f(a))
  }
  final case class Many(a: List[String]) extends OneOrMany[Many] {
    override def map(f: String => String): Many = Many(a.map(f))
  }

  sealed trait Location {
    type T <: OneOrMany[T]
    def value: T
  }

  final case class OneLocation(bucket: String) extends Location {
    override type T = One
    override val value = One(bucket)
  }
  final case class ManyLocation(buckets: List[String]) extends Location {
    override type T = Many
    override val value = Many(buckets)
  }

  class Log[L <: Location](location: L, path: String) {
    def getPath(): L#T = location.value.map(b => s"fs://$b/$path")
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you actually need all that, why not just something like this?

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "${T} is not a valid Location type.")
sealed trait Location[T] {
  def getPath(location: T, path: String): T
}

object Location {
  final def apply[T](implicit location: Location[T]): Location[T] = location

  implicit final val StringLocation: Location[String] =
    new Location[String] {
      override final def getPath(bucket: String, path: String): String =
        s"fs://${bucket}/$path"
    }
  
  implicit final val StringListLocation: Location[List[String]] =
    new Location[List[String]] {
      override final def getPath(buckets: List[String], path: String): List[String] =
        buckets.map(bucket => s"fs://${bucket}/$path")
    }
}

final class Log[L : Location](location: L, path: String) {
  def getPath(): L =
    Location[L].getPath(location, path)
}
```

Which works like this:

```
new Log(location = "root", "foo/bar").getPath()
// val res: String = fs://root/foo/bar

new Log(location = List("base1", "base2"), "foo/bar").getPath()
// val res: List[String] = List(fs://base1/foo/bar, fs://base2/foo/bar)

new Log(location = 10, "foo/bar").getPath()
// Compile time error: Int is not a valid Location type.
```

---

If you really, really, really want to have all those classes you can just do this:

```
sealed trait OneOrMany extends Product with Serializable
final case class One(path: String) extends OneOrMany
final case class Many(paths: List[String]) extends OneOrMany

sealed trait Location extends Product with Serializable {
  type T <: OneOrMany
}

final case class OneLocation(bucket: String) extends Location {
  override final type T = One
}

final case class ManyLocations(buckets: List[String]) extends Location {
  override final type T = Many
}

@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Not found a Path for Path {L}")
sealed trait Path[L <: Location] {
  def getPath(location: L, path: String): L#T
}

object Path {
  implicit final val OneLocationPath: Path[OneLocation] =
    new Path[OneLocation] {
      override final def getPath(location: OneLocation, path: String): One =
        One(path = s"fs://${location.bucket}/$path")
    }
  
  implicit final val ManyLocationsPath: Path[ManyLocations] =
    new Path[ManyLocations] {
      override final def getPath(location: ManyLocations, path: String): Many =
        Many(paths = location.buckets.map(bucket => s"fs://${bucket}/$path"))
    }
}

final class Log[L <: Location](location: L, path: String) {
  def getPath()(implicit ev: Path[L]): L#T =
    ev.getPath(location, path)
}
```

Which works like you want:

```
val onePath: One = new Log(OneLocation("root"), "foo/bar").getPath()
// val onePath: One = One(fs://root/foo/bar)

val manyPath: Many = new Log(ManyLocations(List("base1", "base2")), "foo/bar").getPath()
// val manyPath: Many = Many(List(fs://base1/foo/bar, fs://base2/foo/bar)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for proposing another way. Very interesting. I find that the intent is less clear because it is diluted with technical code for the typeclass mechanism.

Comment: @YannMoisan what do you mean? Why the intent is less clear? which intent do you want? Also, you can just add a typeclass to your existing approach. I just think that you are creating a lot of unnecessary boilerplate classes, but if you actually need them the mix should be simple.

Comment: I thought it's easier to see that there are 2 cases for `Location` with a `Location` ADT.

Comment: @YannMoisan Well you can have the `Location` **ADT** plus a `Path` **typeclass**, I will edit my answer.

Comment: After thinking about it, I agree. It is better to not expose `OneOrMany` (it's an implementation detail) to clients of the method getPath.

Comment: @YannMoisan ok, I any case, I believe you should be able to adapt your code how you want to, given all the answers here. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

For me removal of dependent path works quite well:

```
sealed trait OneOrMany[T] { self: T =>
  def map(f: String => String) : T
}
final case class One(a: String) extends OneOrMany[One] {
  override def map(f: String => String): One = One(f(a))
}
final case class Many(a: List[String]) extends OneOrMany[Many] {
  override def map(f: String => String): Many = Many(a.map(f))
}
  
sealed trait Location[+T] {
  def value: T
}
final case class OneLocation(bucket: String) extends Location[One] {
  override val value = One(bucket)
}
final case class ManyLocation(buckets: List[String]) extends Location[Many] {
  override val value = Many(buckets)
}

// the only place we require OneOrMany[T]
// to provide .map(String => String): T method
class Log[T](location: Location[OneOrMany[T]], path: String) {
  def getPath(): T = location.value.map(b => s"fs://$b/$path")
}
```

```
@ val onePath: One = new Log(OneLocation("root"), "foo/bar").getPath()
onePath: One = One("fs://root/foo/bar")

@ val manyPath: Many = new Log(ManyLocation(List("base1", "base2")), "foo/bar").getPath()
manyPath: Many = Many(List("fs://base1/foo/bar", "fs://base2/foo/bar"))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I don't need an abstract type here. I have the bad reflex to use it when I want to return a different type given the context.

Answer (score 2):

I would replace F-bounded polymorphism with a type class (`Mapper`).

`OneOrMany` is implemetation detail of `Location` but in `location.value.map...` maybe we slightly break encapsulation (`Log` knows not only about `Location` but also about `OneOrMany` and that it can map in `OneOrMany`).

I would avoid type projections (`L#T`) unless they're really necessary (or you use them intentionally).

Here is kind of type-level implementation (although maybe over-engineered)

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.github.dmytromitin" %% "auxify-macros" % "0.8"
import com.github.dmytromitin.auxify.macros.{aux, instance, syntax}
import Mapper.syntax._
import LocMapper.syntax._

sealed trait OneOrMany
final case class One(a: String) extends OneOrMany
final case class Many(a: List[String]) extends OneOrMany

@syntax
trait Mapper[T <: OneOrMany] {
  def map(t: T, f: String => String) : T
}
object Mapper {
  implicit val one: Mapper[One] = (t, f) => One(f(t.a))
  implicit val many: Mapper[Many] = (t, f) => Many(t.a.map(f))
}

@aux
sealed trait Location {
  protected type T <: OneOrMany
  val value: T
}
final case class OneLocation(bucket: String) extends Location {
  override type T = One
  override val value = One(bucket)
}
final case class ManyLocation(buckets: List[String]) extends Location {
  override type T = Many
  override val value = Many(buckets)
}

@aux @instance
trait ToLocation[T <: OneOrMany] {
  type Out <: Location.Aux[T]
  def apply(t: T): Out
}
object ToLocation {
  implicit val one: Aux[One, OneLocation] = instance(t => OneLocation(t.a))
  implicit val many: Aux[Many, ManyLocation] = instance(t => ManyLocation(t.a))
}

@syntax
trait LocMapper[L <: Location] {
  def map(l: L, f: String => String): L
}
object LocMapper {
  implicit def mkLocMapper[T <: OneOrMany, L <: Location.Aux[T]](implicit
    ev: L <:< Location.Aux[T],
    m: Mapper[T],
    toLoc: ToLocation.Aux[T, L]
  ): LocMapper[L] = (l, f) => toLoc(l.value.map(f))
}

class Log[L <: Location : LocMapper](location: L, path: String) {
  def getPath(): L = location.map(b => s"fs://$b/$path")
}

val onePath: OneLocation = new Log(OneLocation("root"), "foo/bar").getPath()
// OneLocation(fs://root/foo/bar)
val manyPath: ManyLocation = new Log(ManyLocation(List("base1", "base2")), "foo/bar").getPath()
// ManyLocation(List(fs://base1/foo/bar, fs://base2/foo/bar))
```